# Angular 2.0.0 - Testing " imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule' "

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I am having a problem in testing app.component.ts in Angular 2. I am using angular-cli. Whenever I run ng test, my app.component.spec.ts makes the console prompt with the error:

```
 Failed: Unexpected directive 'HomeModuleComponent' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
 Error: Unexpected directive 'HomeModuleComponent' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
```

I imported the HomeModuleComponent in TestBed

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports : [ HomeModuleComponent ]
});
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: I think I have found the problem as of now. The HomeModuleComponent must be in the declarations not in the imports. Moreover, can you import a Module in your TestBed? Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`HomeModuleComponent` is `Component` not the `Module`, so it has to be in declarations:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeModuleComponent],
  imports : [ ]
});
```

and then you can create the component to test as,

```
TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
```

Answer (score 4):

In my test spec, by mistake I was importing a `service` instead of providing it. I was getting the same error.

Adding the `service` back inside `providers` array resolved my error.